# Can I remove openbox if I want to keep lxde?

Tags: lxde, openbox

In the user greeting session, I have 'ubuntu', 'lxde' and 'openbox'. I don't know why I have openbox, so can I remove it by typing:

```
 sudo apt purge --autoremove openbox
```

Does this command affect my lxde desktop environment?

Comment: Rename the openbox file in `/usr/share/xsessions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Openbox](http://openbox.org/wiki/LXDE):

> Desktop Environment, developed by "PCMan" in Taiwan, aimed at lean elegant code and usable design.
>   Uses Openbox as the Window Manager, with lightweight modular components in addition.

So, if you want to keep `LXDE`, you cannot remove `openbox`.

Comment: How can I remove it from log in session?